# What does current() reference inside a predicate that's inside a for-each in XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Very often I see code something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/catalog/cd/artist">
    <xsl:sort select="artist"/>
    ...business logic...
    <xsl:variable name="artistNum" select="artist_number"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="/catalog/cd/song[song_artist_number = $artistNum]/song_title"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The variable `artistNum` is only used the once, in the `value-of` to make sure the correct node is used. These nums act similar to foreign keys in SQL, but in XML.  I read [on W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/func_current.asp) that `current()` and `.` do have slightly different meanings in one specific scenario. So I'm wondering if the following would also be correct, allowing the nearly useless variable `artistNum` to be gotten rid of.

```
<xsl:for-each select="/catalog/cd/artist">
    <xsl:sort select="artist"/>
    ...business logic...
    <xsl:value-of select="/catalog/cd/song[song_artist_number = current()/artist_number]/song_title"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But I'm not sure if `current()` in that context is referring to the `song` because it's in the predicate, or the `artist` from the `for-each`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `current()` refers to the current node. :)

```
<xsl:for-each select="/catalog/cd/artist">
    <!-- processes `<artist>` elements - current() always refers to that element --->
</xsl:for-each>
```

`current()` exists to overcome the problem that `.` refers to the node that the XPath predicate is operating on, and that XPath (from within its limited view of the world) doesn't have access to XSLT's context.

This makes no sense, because `<artist_number>` probably isn't a child of `<song>`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/catalog/cd/song[song_artist_number = ./artist_number]/song_title"/>
```

This makes sense, because `<artist_number>` probably *is* a child of `<artist>`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/catalog/cd/artist">
  <xsl:value-of select="/catalog/cd/song[song_artist_number = current()/artist_number]/song_title"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

A few things in XSLT change the `current()` node - most notably `<xsl:for-each>` and `<xsl:apply-templates>` (but not `<xsl:call-template>`).

Fundamentally, `.` is an XPath concept. It refers to different nodes at different locations in an XPath expression. `current()` is an XSLT concept. Its refers a single node until the processing context of the XSLT program changes. It's also not available outside of XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to explain it a different way from @Tomalak (though his explanation is not wrong).

Think of current() as a variable rather than a function. It could easily have been named $xsl:current. Whereever you see an XPath expression in a stylesheet, say `select="XXXXXX"`, then replace that with

```
let $xsl:current := . return XXXXXX
```

So whenever execution switches from XSLT to XPath, the `$xsl:current` variable is implcitly bound to the value of "."; and when "." changes because of an XPath construct such as a predicate, the variable `$xsl:current` retains its original value.